# How to detect CPU speed on Windows 64bit?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, 64-bit, cpu-speed

I've found the following code from here "http://www.boyet.com/Articles/CodeFromInternet.html".
It returns the speed of the CPU in GHz but works only on 32bit Windows.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace CpuSpeed
{
    class Program
    {
        static double? GetCpuSpeedInGHz()
        {
            double? GHz = null;
            using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
                {
                    GHz = 0.001 * (UInt32) mo.Properties["CurrentClockSpeed"].Value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return GHz;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The current CPU speed is {0}", (GetCpuSpeedInGHz() ?? -1.0).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've searched for 64bit management classes, but without success.
Is there any other method to get the CPU speed under 64bit Windows?

Comment: Uhm.. what makes you think that this only works on 32bit Windows?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've used the following code based on the answer by Binoj Antony which returns the speed for each CPU/core, not only the first one:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registrykeyHKLM = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
string cpuPath = @"HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor";
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registrykeyCPUs = registrykeyHKLM.OpenSubKey(cpuPath, false);
StringBuilder sbCPUDetails = new StringBuilder();
int iCPUCount;
for (iCPUCount = 0; iCPUCount < registrykeyCPUs.SubKeyCount; iCPUCount++)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registrykeyCPUDetail = registrykeyHKLM.OpenSubKey(cpuPath + "\\" + iCPUCount, false);
    string sMHz = registrykeyCPUDetail.GetValue("~MHz").ToString();
    string sProcessorNameString = registrykeyCPUDetail.GetValue("ProcessorNameString").ToString();
    sbCPUDetails.Append(Environment.NewLine + "\t" + string.Format("CPU{0}: {1} MHz for {2}", new object[] { iCPUCount, sMHz, sProcessorNameString }));
    registrykeyCPUDetail.Close();
}
registrykeyCPUs.Close();
registrykeyHKLM.Close();
sCPUSpeed = iCPUCount++ + " core(s) found:" + sbCPUDetails.ToString();
```

Fell free to customize it for your needs.

Comment: does this return the current speed or the maximum speed?

Answer (score 6):

Code below should do the trick

```
  RegistryKey registrykeyHKLM = Registry.LocalMachine;
  string keyPath = @"HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0";
  RegistryKey registrykeyCPU = registrykeyHKLM.OpenSubKey(keyPath, false);
  string MHz = registrykeyCPU.GetValue("~MHz").ToString();
  string ProcessorNameString = (string)registrykeyCPU.GetValue("ProcessorNameString");
  registrykeyCPU.Close();
  registrykeyHKLM.Close();
  Console.WriteLine("{0} MHz for {1}", MHz, ProcessorNameString);
```

Comment: I've rewritten the code as contained some bugs and only returned the MHz for CPU/code 0. See my marked reply. Thanks a lot for your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of the answer provided by Binoj would be as follows. This will return the maximum clock speed of your CPU. Please note that if you want the total available cycles on the machine you should multiply this value by `Environment.ProcessorCount`.

```
private float GetCpuClockSpeed()
{
    return (int) Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0", "~MHz", 0);
}
```

Comment: Take note that although most processors on the market today use same clock for all cores but there might be some that don't. you have to sum all speeds for all cores.